# Proxying FTP Over MQTT

Tags: ftp, reverse-proxy, haproxy, mqtt

Considering we have established a secure connection via MQTT (Let's say to AWS-IoT /Azure etc) can we then use it to tunnel FTP server running on Embedded Device (For remote access)?

If it's possible, would it work with the raw ftp data being sent over mqtt Or some sort of translator of mqtt payload to ftp messages is a must?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's theoretically possible but I've never heard of or seen such an implementation.

MQTT is a transport protocol between publishers and subscribers.  You could piggy back FTP commands and data transfers on MQTT but you would need endpoint translators to convert to/from FTP <--> MQTT on both sides potentially.

So tldr; possible but not easily without a large coding effort.

But in the end, what problem does it solve?  Performance? Security? Reliability?